# How to break away from LaCie Big Disk Extreme firmware, for its two disks to appear as two instead of one?

Tags: hard-drive, firmware

## Question

How can I reconfigure a LaCie Big Disk Extreme so that Mountain Lion will see both of its disks?

### Background

Once, years ago, I accidentally did something bad to a LaCie device. Where normally its two disks appeared to Mac OS X as one larger disk, the accident caused the two smaller disks to appear. At the time, I chose to resolve the issue by reinstalling firmware with a LaCie-provided utility.

Now: I probably need to 'break away' from that RAID-oriented firmware – intentionally, not accidentally.

I don't want to create two *volumes*, neither can I place the disks in different enclosures.

I want to work with the two separate *disks* with the current enclosure, so that I can experiment with things such as ZFS.

When I last checked, in 2012, LaCie's firmware utility for this class of drive could not run on Lion.

Data in this enclosure is, always will be, disposable.

#### System information for the device

```
LaCie Big Disk Extreme LUN 0:

  Manufacturer:     LaCie Group SA
  Model:            0x1
  GUID:             0xD04B5A0E058DF1
  Maximum Speed:    Up to 800 Mb/sec
  Connection Speed: Up to 800 Mb/sec
  Sub-units:
    LaCie Big Disk Extreme LUN 0 Unit:
      Unit Software Version:  0x10483
      Unit Spec ID:           0x609E
      Firmware Revision:      0x102
      Product Revision Level: 912
```

Comment: Would a good keyword for this be **JBOD**? If so, maybe we should move this question to Server Fault or Super User, where that's a recognised tag (respectively: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/jbod and http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/jbod).

Comment: I'm looking for exactly the same, same Lacie, want 2 separate drives. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @user45635 nothing yet. If I find one I'll add an answer.